# AWS S3 Pre-signed URL - Save JSON in batches

Tags: json, amazon-s3

My client-side application maintains a JSON file for each customer, a file that contains a list of customer's taken actions like clicks, navigations, etc. I use those files for data analysis purposes.
I'm saving those JSONs inside a dedicated AWS S3 bucket, and I'm using the pre-signed URL feature to do it.
The current design requires me to load the whole JSON when the customer enters the application, so I can continue adding the new actions taken to it. I'm saving this JSON each 60 seconds.
[image]

I'm trying to find a better approach to handle it, and try to avoid the initial JSON loading.
Is there an option to save this JSON by chunks, means that every 60 seconds it will save a minimal amount of JSON data that will eventually be merged into the whole original JSON, without the need to fully load it as the customer enters the application?

I've heard about **multipart upload**, but I want to hear your feedback.
Thanks!

Comment: You could save a new object every 60 seconds, then have some backend process concatenate the newly created objects with some frequency like daily.

Comment: are you sending previous data relevant to user interactions before customer logs in ? Multi part upload can be used if the data load is huge (recommended if more than 100 MB and required if a single record size is 5 GB) and I don't think it's practical to use with a 60 sec interval.

Comment: You can also use a Kinesis Data Stream and add the data belonging to a particular user in a shard. If you want to apply some transformations before saving the JSON file in the S3 bucket you can attach a lambda function to do the same. You can insert data related to a particular user in the same shard every time by generating the partition key with a unique value belonging to the user (for example, email of user or user_id).